# Sprint boot - Auto configure to call a REST service on startup

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a requirement to create an auto-configuration for service call on spring-boot startup.

i.e., During spring-boot startup, the below service has to be called.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/addProduct", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody String addProduct(@RequestBody String productStr) {
    ..<My code>..
}
```

The add product requires an input like:

```
{
  "product":"test",
  "price":"10"
}
```

This will internally call a database service.

During startup, the json input provided in the console should be fed to this service.

I have no idea on how to achieve this. Verified a couple of Spring documentation. But those does'nt suit the requirement.

Kindly help in explaining a way or providing a right documentation to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is by implementing ApplicationRunner like this :

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ApplicationInitializer implements ApplicationRunner {

    private ProductController productController;

    public ApplicationInitializer(ProductController productController) {
        this.productController = productController;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        String productArg = args.getOptionValues("product").get(0); // Assume that you will have only one product argument
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Product product = mapper.readValue(productArg, Product.class);
        String response = productController.add(product);

        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

The run method will be invoked at startup with arguments passed in the command line like this : `java -jar yourApp.jar --product="{\"name\":\"test\", \"price\":\"15\"}"`.

And you need a class to map the json to an object like this :

```java
public class Product {

    private String name;

    private int price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

You can also call your Controller using the RestTemplate (or WebClient) if needed :

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Component
public class ApplicationInitializer implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        String productArg = args.getOptionValues("product").get(0); // Assume that you will have only one product argument
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Product product = mapper.readValue(productArg, Product.class);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String response = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/products", product, String.class);

        System.out.println(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is a good alternative. !! Thank you very much !!

Comment: However, just being curious, is there a way to do this completely on auto configuration? The solution you provided is just calling the rest service while startup.

Comment: What do you mean by auto configuration? You can call a method after you bean is created using the @PostConstruct annotation on a method but you can't pass parameters to it. You can find others ways here : https://www.baeldung.com/running-setup-logic-on-startup-in-spring

Answer (score 1):

Such requirement can be achieved by using an `init()` method annotated with `@PostConstruct` in a bean.

e.g.

```java
    @Component
    public class Foo {
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
       //Call your service
    }
   }
```